# Help with streaming AR.Drone camera images to openCV

Tags: ros, opencv, stream

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I am using the AR.Drone 2.0 and setup the ardrone_autonomy driver link:[text](https:// github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy) and I also installed ROS from the official website (fuerte). I am using Ubuntu 12.0.4 also.

What I would like to do is be able to write a program that takes the camera stream from the AR.Drone 2.0 and sends them to openCV. openCV is installed with my ROS distribution inside the vision_opencv folder (it has cv_bridge and openCV2 which is what I would like to use).

I have played around with openCV2 from the openCV website for single images so openCV seems to work well. I am slightly confused on how to solve the above problem because I am new to ROS and openCV. I have followed the tutorials but they do not teach me how to deal with this problem as far as I understand.

I think there are two problems to what I want to do. 1) send camera images directly from the AR.Drone to ROS. 2) send images from ROS format to openCV and do this the other way around. I read that cv_bridge does this but slightly overwhelmed by it.

Ideally, I want a GUI with the images going into openCV but how will I know if the images are successfully going into openCV? openCV is just a package and doesnt seem to have an interface like MATLAB so I want to also understand what kind of output I should expect to know if the program is working correctly. Any help will be great!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79306/help-with-streaming-ar.drone-camera-images-to-opencv/) by [MichaelJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/6706/michaelj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-09-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-09-15**:
How are the images currently streamed? Can it be used as a sort of IP cam? OpenCV has support for IP cams.

**Comment by [MichaelJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/6706/michaelj/) on 2013-09-15**:
Currently, the images stream using Qt from the code provided by the ardrone_tutorials. The ardrone sends the images through the generates an ad-Hoc wifi. What does IP stand for?

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2013-10-30**:
Do you want to get the stream from the AR.Drone in order to process it with OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The AR.Drone Autonomy package publishes the video captured by the cameras in the topic `/ardrone/image_raw` topic. I have prepared a simple code that works with opencv so that you get the idea:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <cv_bridge/CvBridge.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
   
static const char WINDOW[]="RGB Image";
static const char WINDOW2[]="Gray Image";

void process(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& cam_image){
   sensor_msgs::CvBridge bridge; 
   Mat img_rgb = bridge.imgMsgToCv(cam_image,"bgr8"); 
   Mat img_gray;

   cvtColor(img_rgb,img_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

   imshow(WINDOW,img_rgb);
   imshow(WINDOW2,img_gray);
   cvWaitKey(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc,argv,"Display_Images");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it(n);
  image_transport::Subscriber image_sub = it.subscribe("/ardrone/image_raw",1,process);
 
  cv::namedWindow(WINDOW);
  cv::namedWindow(WINDOW2);
    
  cv::destroyWindow(WINDOW);
  cv::destroyWindow(WINDOW2);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

If  you are interesed in switching between the front and bottom cameras you can use the command:

```
rosservice call /ardrone/togglecam
```

You can also subscribe to `/ardrone/bottom/image_raw` if you want to work only with the bottom camera.

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) with karma: 182 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/6706/michaelj/) on 2013-10-30**:
That helps so much, thank you! Out of curiosity, are you working with the ardrone_autonomy package? Have you been getting a nice stream output or does it produce blurry/double images?

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2013-10-30**:
Yes I'm working with the ardrone_autonomy package. The images are of good quality. Good luck!

**Comment by [MichaelJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/6706/michaelj/) on 2013-10-30**:
Thanks. So when you ran rosrun image_view image_view image :=/ardrone/front/image_raw, was the image quality good? Did you change any code in the ardrone autonomy or calibrate the camera?

**Comment by [huevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/21145/huevos/) on 2014-12-17**:
Hello,
I have the cv_bridge.h but not the CvBridge.h , my prog can't be run because of this include.
How can I fix this?
Thank you!

**Comment by [ffazlurr](https://answers.ros.org/users/23002/ffazlurr/) on 2015-07-01**:
I have some probelm with huevos, if you dont mind please upload your CvBridge.h thanks

**Comment by [renanchagas](https://answers.ros.org/users/23669/renanchagas/) on 2015-08-24**:
Hello! I`m new in ROS. What I have to do to run the code above? Do I have to compile? Thanks

**Comment by [enthurzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31050/enthurzan/) on 2017-07-06**:
I tried running this program, but I got this error when I built it even after I installeed the vision_opencv package

```
fatal error: cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.
findtag/CMakeFiles/detect.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'findtag/CMakeFiles/detect.di